# What is the name of the vacuous type/class in the python language

Tags: python

Is there a type in python which is a subtype of every type?
I see some mention of the `NoneType`, but it appears that `None` is an element of this type.  e.g., `isinstance(None,type(None))` --> `True`

I.e. a type `T` for which `isinstance(x,T)` returns `False` for every `x`,
and for which `issubclass(A,T)` returns `True` for any class `A` ?

Comment: no, there isn't

Comment: I believe you can implement such a type with some nasty hacks, but I can't think of a single use-case where this is going to be useful

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah, probably using [this part of the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks)

Comment: I would think you meant `issubclass(T, A)` returns True. I'm not aware of *any* type system that includes (or can include) such a type. (Maybe under row polymorphism, where the empty row could be considered a subclass of any non-empty row. Python doesn't use row polymorphism, though.)

Comment: The `None` type itself isn't related any other class. The *semantics* of its single value is to indicate the *absence* of a value of any type. (That is, `None` can be distinguished at the type level from any instance of any type.)

Comment: @DeepSpace Things like this tend to be useful when writing generic type algebra code. E.g. the requested type is the identity value for the "union" operation.

Comment: Intesting.  every type system I've every worked with has an empty type which is a subtype of every type.    Corresponding to the fact that the empy set is a subset of every set. Funny that people are saying: I'm not aware of any type system that includes (or can include) such a type.

Comment: @JimNewton Which type system did you have in mind that *does*?

Comment: The two that I'm most familiar with are are Common Lisp and Scala.   However any type system which supports intersections would necessarily support the empty type if you ask for the intersection of two disjoint types.

Comment: @JimNewton The difference is that before type hinting was added, there were no type algebra functions -- you couldn't ask for the intersection or union of types.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, every class inherits from a built-in basic class called `object`.

That overall grandparent class may be what you're looking for, but if you really mean a type that is a *sub*type of all others, that isn't a thing in most type systems.

Comment: the empty type is a type in *most* type systems.  At least all that I've worked with.   The empty type is extremely useful for error detection.   For example, if you know x is in T1 and x is in T2, but that the intersection of T1 and T2 is empty, then x is a member of the empty type, thus you've found a runtime/compiletime error to report back to the user.

Comment: @JimNewton I'm not sure I follow. "`x` cannot exist" is different from saying that "`x` is a member of an empty type". In Haskell, for example, `Void` is not a *subtype* of anything, though it is the initial object in the category of types.

Comment: sorry, but how are those different:  x cannot exist vs x is a member of the empty set/type?  I'm not a haskell-ite, but I was under the impression that Haskell does not support subtyping.  Maybe I'm misinformed about that.

Comment: "empty" =/= "subtype of all other types"